# PHP how to get revision number file in SVN

Tags: php, svn

Say I have a file in a SVN. How do I use PHP to check the file's revision number?

I see the SVN function list at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.svn.php but am not sure which one to use or the exact code to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_revision($filename) {
    $status = @shell_exec('svnversion '.realpath($filename));
    if ( preg_match('/\d+/', $status, $match) ) {
       return $match[0];
    }else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [`svn_status`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-status.php).

Usage would be something like:

```
$status = svn_status('path/to/file');
$revision = $status[0]['cmt_rev'];
```

You definitely *don't* want to be using `svn_blame`, as that's a very expensive operation (it has to retrieve a lot of history for the file to figure out who changed what, and that means (slow) requests to the server).

Comment: This is assuming that you want to get the information from a checkout, rather than from the repository itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the svn_blame() function to get informations, including the revision number, about the file in your SVN repository.